# Code inside eventListener isn't called immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, addeventlistener

I am trying to understand this code but it is not making any sense. 
When `#open_help` button is clicked he is calling the `handleOpen()` which calls `showHelp()`, which calls jQuery function to show the help div, but if you see below that he is adding and removing an event listener and he also calls `hideHelp()`. Why is he doing that?

Is he just doing that to encapsulate hideHelp so it would wait for the button to be clicked?

```
// listen to "help" button
$('#open_help').bind("click",handleOpenHelp);

function handleOpenHelp(evt) {
    if (!$("#help").is(":visible")) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        showHelp();
    }
}



function showHelp() {
    $("#help").show();

    document.addEventListener("click",function __handler__(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        document.removeEventListener("click",__handler__,true);
        hideHelp();
    },true);
}



function hideHelp() {
    $("#help").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the code to the bare minimum and re-arrange it a bit to see what's going on:

```
$("#help").show(); // Show the help dialog

// If user clicks ANYWHERE (the whole document)
document.addEventListener("click",function __handler__(evt){
    hideHelp(); // Hide the help dialog

    // Remove myself from the event listener so that this function
    // will not be called again when user clicks anywhere:
    document.removeEventListener("click",__handler__,true);
},true);
```

So basically it's grabbing all click events anywhere on anything (button, text, link, blank space.. literally anywhere) and execute a function to hide the help dialog. After doing that (before in the original code) it removes itself from the click event handler so that other things on the page can get clicks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll notice hide help is basically part of "Click" event listener that is being appended onto the document element after a person clicks help.  this means once the help info is shown, all you have to do is click anywhere on the page and what was shown will once again be hidden.

stoppropigation and stopImmediatePropogation are just insurance that nothing else will happen accept what he wants. It stops all eventhandlers and parent eventhandlers in their tracks.

He then removes the "Click" event listener that was added when the show event was fired.  It will be added again once help is clicked.

then finally he hides the help element and waits for help to be clicked again.

Hope this answers your question.